# .net core Custom oauth2 login and Google login api together get error

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0

I'm using .net core 2 and add AddAuthentication() by Google and a custom oauth 2 login api

but both of these authentications got error
google say :

> Exception: The oauth state was missing or invalid.

custom login say :

> Mismatching redirect URI.

When I disable(comment) the custom login api from startup file
and use the only google login api
everything is OK

```
services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddOAuth("test", options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = "..Id...";
                options.ClientSecret ="..Secret..";
                options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/Account/ExternalLoginCallback");

                options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://example.com/oauth/authorize";
                options.TokenEndpoint = "https://example.com/oauth/token";
                options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://example.com/oauth/api/o";

                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "name");
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Email, "EmailAddress", ClaimValueTypes.Email);

                options.Events = new OAuthEvents
                {
                    OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
                    {
                        var request =
                            new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
                        request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                        request.Headers.Authorization =
                            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);

                        var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request,
                            HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                        var user = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

                        context.RunClaimActions(user);
                    }
                };
            })
            .AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
            {
                googleOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
                googleOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
            });
```

Is there any problem with my code or any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

in my case issue was in CallbackPath and schema 
and I check AuthorizationEndpoint, TokenEndpoint, UserInformationEndpoint 
with postman and find some issues, fixed these issues and everything is ok.